# requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT), REQUEST_CODE) not showing pop up in Android 10 but its working in Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth

The below code is Working for `Android 12` but same not working `Android 10` the problem its it showing the run time permission pop up for BLUETOOTH_CONNECT

Here is the below code i have written inside the fragment

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private var ctx: Context? = null
    val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

    companion object {
        private const val BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_CODE = 100
        private const val BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION_CODE = 101
    }


    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        this.ctx = view.context
        //get the devie manifrature name
        System.out.println(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)
        //get the type of the bluetooth device
        getBluetoothDeviceType()
        checkPermission(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION_CODE
        )
        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun requestBluetoothPermission() {

    }

    private fun getBluetoothDeviceType() {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                ctx!!,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            if (BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_CELLULAR == 0x0204) {
                System.out.println("permission is granted")
            }


        } else {
            if (BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_CELLULAR != 0x0204) {
                System.out.println("permission is not granted")
            }
        }


    }

    private fun checkPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                ctx!! as Activity,
                permission
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                println("permission is not required")
            } else {
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
            }

            // Requesting the permission

            //Fragment.requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(ctx!! as Activity, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            //permission granted
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    // Handle the situation where Bluetooth is not available
                } else {
                    // Get a set of currently paired devices
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            ctx!! as Activity,
                            permissions[0]
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices

                        // If there are paired devices
                        if (pairedDevices.isNotEmpty()) {
                            // Loop through paired devices
                            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                                // Check if the device is a scanner
                                if (device.bluetoothClass.majorDeviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING) {
                                    // Device is a scanner
                                    val scannerDevice = device
                                    println("Scanner found: ${scannerDevice.name}")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Handle the situation where there are no paired devices
                        }
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(
                        ctx!! as Activity,
                        "Bluetooth Connect Permission Granted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    ctx!! as Activity,
                    "Bluetooth Connect Permission Denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

here how below my build.gradle looks like

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `requireActivity()` instead of `ctx!! as Activity`? Also, logging on Android is typically done with `android.util.Log`, not `System.out.println`.

Comment: In any case, `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` was added in API level 31 (Android 12). Read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare

Comment: @Michael what should I used instead of that in Android 10

Comment: See the link I posted in my previous comment